# What is the title of the song that played in Yosuga no Sora episode 10?

Tags: music, yosuga-no-sora

I need to know the name of the music that was playing in episode 10 of the anime Yosuga no Sora.

I mean the music that started at the 19:10 mark or the music that started when Haru saw Sora masturbating.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's ["Tomadoi no Naka"](https://soundcloud.com/soniko-strange/yosuga-no-sora-tomadoi-no-naka) (戸惑いの中), from the *Yosuga No Sora Original Soundtrack -New-* (ヨスガノソラ オリジナルサウンドトラック－New－).

Answer (score 0):

its from the Yosuga no Sora OST -New-, in english its called, "in the midst of bewilderment" I believe